# Read a file using URL

Tags: java, java-6

I am trying to read a file using URL in java.

```
FileHelper.read(new File(getClass.getResource("TextFile.rtf")))
```

I am really confused with the below exception

```
error: overloaded method constructor File with alternatives:
  (java.net.URI)java.io.File <and>
  (java.lang.String)java.io.File
  cannot be applied to (java.net.URL)
```

Any idea or suggestion how can I resolve this exception.

Thanks !!!

Comment: did you mean `getClass().getResource("TextFile.rtf");` ?

Comment: The `File` class takes a `URI` not a `URL` as an argument. `getResource()` returns a `URL`.

Comment: Updated my post as URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try converting the `URL` to its `URI` equivalent:

```
FileHelper.read(new File(getClass.getResource("TextFile.rtf").toURI()))
```

See [**`URL.toURI()`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#toURI%28%29) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to get URI from the URL.

```
URL url = getClass.getResource("TextFile.rtf");
URI uri = url.toURI();
FileHelper.read(new File(uri))
```